# Getting list of Apps instaleld on my iPad from iTunes

Tags: itunes, ios

Is there an easy way to get the screens of my apps and list of their names from the iTunes App management tab? I would like to post them on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean from the App tab for your iPad within iTunes desktop app, that allows you to select which apps to sync, and re-order your home screens in.

If this is the case, then no.  To start with, the sort options are only for Name/Kind/Category/Date/Size, so there is no way to separate between installed and not installed.  Even if there is, there is no way to cut that information in any way.

Third party tools like Phoneview and such may be able to provide a directory listing of installed apps which you can then manipulate to use on your website, but I don't use any so I will just throw it out in case it jogs anyone else's memory.

The only simple way to share, is to either take screen grabs of the iTunes windows to just screenshot (hold HOME and tap POWER) your whole iPad.  Or type them up...